# Test class with several method object

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, refactoring

I have a class whith some complex logic, so I decide to use the use [method object](https://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceMethodWithMethodObject.html) several times to refactoring it .

Suppose a class like next:

```
public class MapperClass {

    Entity entity = new Entity(); 
    private final Item item;

    public MapperClass(Item item) {
       this.item = item;
    }

    public Entity getEntity() {
          entity.setPrice(extractPrice());
         //more long and complicated implementation
         //mapped from item values
         //entity.set....
         //...
         return entity;
    }

    private double extractPrice() {
        double priceExtracted = 0d;
        //Long and complicated implementation
        //extracted from item
        //...
        return priceExtracted ;
    }

    private List<SubItem> getSubItemsMapped() {
       //Long and complicated implementation
       //extracted from item
       //...
    }

}
```

I refactor it to:

```
 public class MapperClass{

    private Entity entity = new Entity(); 
    private final Item item;

    public MapperClass(Item item) {
       this.item = item;
    }

    public Entity getEntity() {
          entity.setPrice(extractPrice());
          entity.setSubEntities(getSubItemsMapped());
         //more long and complicated implementation
         //mapped from item values
         //entity.set....
         //...
         return entity;
    }

    private double extractPrice() {
        new PriceCalculator(item).getPrice();
    }

    private List<SubItem> getSubItemsMapped() {
       new SubItemsMapper(item).getSubItems();
    }

   //More similar cases
}
```

So then I have a class whith several `method objects` which is cleaner than the one complicated class.

Then when I go to do my tests, I've got the doubt how to test this class.

Which is the best way to test a class with a [method object](https://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceMethodWithMethodObject.html)?

- Test only the class with the `method objects`
- Test all classes, **method object classes** independently and then the **class with method objects**, all in deep.
- Test all classes, but the **method objects classes** in deep, and the **class with method objects** with a simple class to check it is at least mapped by this method objects.
- It has a bad design so rethink how to design it, and then test it.
- Other options.

What is usually done in these cases?

Comment: Fyi: I added another paragraph to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do what you always do when thinking about unit-testing:

- You look at the *public* interface that class X is exposing. Meaning: which methods will be called on objects of that class; what are the parameters; what is the contract of each method.
- You write test cases that fully cover the contract of each method.

That tells you: your "method classes" (I would rather call them "service classes") are subject for intensive unit testing; to make sure that the "service" they deliver ... is actually delivered.

For your MapperClass, you could theoretically re-use those testcases; as the "really public" contract is probably with that MapperClass.

But of course: that would mean "code duplication"; and if you think about it: that MapperClass only "needs" some kind of "plumbing test". Meaning: you only *need* to test that those method classes are correctly called to provide the required result. You do not need to run **all** your tests against the MapperClass.

When avoiding those calls to `new` in your methods in MapperClass (for example by turning the method objects into fields, and using constructor telescoping and dependency injection), then you could even use a mocking framework to simply check: when I call the "outer" method; the correct method object is invoked.

One caveat though: when you don't have that full "contract checking" suites for MapperClass and you later decide to refactor again then you are "broken". Because all that contract checking test code is "attached" to the specific "method class". So you would then have to move all those test to "MapperClass scope". So you should make that decision consciously (but I still advocate to *not* duplicate test code; and go for the solution outlined above - but you should understand this important consequence of that decision).